# Cannot find the class file for org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to move my project to `Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE` and can't compile the source code with a following error:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire. Fix the build path then try building this project

The type org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Where `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire` can be found ?

**UPDATED**

I use Maven in order to build the project:

parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Own Pleasure</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.boot.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</springframework.boot.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>api</module>
        <module>dashboard</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

common pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <hibernate-jpa.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate-jpa.version>
        <querydsl.version>4.1.4</querydsl.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.5</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-collections4.version>4.1</commons-collections4.version>
        <togglz.version>2.3.0.Final</togglz.version>
        <UserAgentUtils.version>1.20</UserAgentUtils.version>
        <imgscalr-lib.version>4.2</imgscalr-lib.version>

        <apt-maven-plugin.version>1.1.3</apt-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.5</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-collections4.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Liquibase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QueryDSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
            <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
            <version>${UserAgentUtils.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Togglz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
            <artifactId>togglz-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${togglz.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
            <artifactId>togglz-spring-security</artifactId>
            <version>${togglz.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.imgscalr/imgscalr-lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${imgscalr-lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${apt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            <options>
                                <querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
                                <querydsl.useFields>true</querydsl.useFields>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>target/generated-sources/java</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Because your classpath is wrong. That is what the exception is telling you.

Comment: How to find what is wrong in the classpath ? I have no idea how to determine the cause of this issue

Comment: Depends on what you use.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire or org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired?

Comment: @eltabo - Autowire

Comment: how do you build the project. do you have a pom.xml

Comment: Could you show us a piece of code where you use 'Autowire'?

Comment: @eltabo this is the biggest issue because it is indirectly referenced from required .class and I have no idea what this class is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange issue... I have removed my Maven repository and re-downloaded it once again.. and the issue is gone

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with spring boot version 3.0.5. Instead of downgrading your spring boot version to match your Java upgrade your Java Version.

I have upgraded Java Version from 11 to 17.

Upgrading always provides enhanced security.

Answer (score -1):

Read the Error, classpath is wrong.